# Where are Settings values saved in QML?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, settings

I am using QtCreator for a C++/QML application. I want to save some application settings and I reached this goal using a code that is very similar to the documentation at this [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html).

```
...
import Qt.labs.settings 1.0

Settings {
    id: settingsValues
    property int sliderValue: 300000
    property bool checkBoxChecked: true
}
...
```

**Questions**

1) Where are these values saved? Maybe is there a file generated expressly for storing these variables? How can I retrieve this file?

2) How the application knows that it has to load these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1 is answered by the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-settings-settings.html):

> The information is stored in the system registry on Windows, and in XML preferences files on macOS. On other Unix systems, in the absence of a standard, INI text files are used. See QSettings documentation for more details.

Question 2: If they exist in the settings, they will be [loaded](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtdeclarative/src/imports/settings/qqmlsettings.cpp.html#_ZN19QQmlSettingsPrivate4loadEv).

The relevant code is (Line 311 as of writing). The *if clause* decides whether the application loads that value or not:

```
if (!currentValue.isNull() && (!previousValue.isValid()
        || (currentValue.canConvert(previousValue.type()) && previousValue != currentValue))) {
    property.write(q, currentValue);
    qCDebug(lcSettings) << "QQmlSettings: load" << property.name() << "setting:" << currentValue << "default:" << previousValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I chose to leave the answer of @derM as accepted answer because it was very helpful for the question 2. 
Nevertheless I post this answer because it is the correct answer for the question 1 in my situation.

I am using QtCreator on Ubuntu 16.04, so I found the configuration file at the following path:

> default_Directory_Of_My_Project/**.config/Unknown Organization/myProject.conf**

Answer (score 0):

I'm on macOS and I did search everywhere I could in my user directory, but never found it.

My code is:

```
Settings {
        id: settings
        fileName: "settings"
        property alias x: root.x
        property alias y: root.y
}
```

Finally I found it inside my build directory (to be precise, the path set in Projects > Build Settings > Build directory)
the in the .app/Contents/MacOS/
and the file is named as *`fileName`* property (so *settings.xml* for me)

To recap, on macOS: *build_directory/****XXX*.app/Contents/MacOS/*`fileName`***

(for me: *XXX.app/Contents/MacOS/settings*)